The object specified does not belong to a list - SharePoint Online PowerShell script
I am trying to get one of the properties (Batch date) of the SharePoint online document library file.  I am getting below error Any suggestion on this please.
Batch date is single line of text field having date value.
Script:

Error message:
Get-PnPFile : The object specified does not belong to a list.
At line:9 char:10

$File1 = Get-PnPFile -Url $FileRelativeURL -AsListItem

     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPFile], ServerException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Files.GetFile
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:13 char:1


Write-Host $File1["Batch_x0020_Date"]

  + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray





How about using the direct URL instead of the relative URL in your script?

Hi @Allen_MSFT
I have used the direct file URL getting "Get-PnPFile : The object specified does not belong to a list." error Please assist.                                                             $FileRelativeURL = https://AAAA.sharepoint.com/sites/TestDocuments/Documents/test.txt
